# How to stop highlights of static import methods/constants in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, static-import, android-studio-import

I am using static imports in Android Studio as:

```
import static android.opengl.GLES20.*;
```

But android studio highlighting every static member/constant related to static import in code as.

[image]

I've also tried to look for an option in `Settings > Editor > Color & Fonts > Java` but found nothing about changing color.

Comment: In `Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Java`  you are given a code snippet, you can click on the highlighted variables/classes and are redirected to the corresponding attribute - is there really nothing what matches your case?

Comment: Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Java  Save as new template.. Staticfield/method you can edit Foreground and Background ?

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu That affects only members/constants declared with in class, no changes in members and constants used from static imports from other classes.

Comment: @Amy : Yes there is no attribute in this case.

Comment: by 'highlighting', do you mean it changes its color to purple? Do you want to keep it black?

Comment: @khusrav it's default highlight color for static import related members/constants, and simply I don't want it to be highlighted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As your problem is just the highlighting after you used "add on demand static import" and not for the style in general, the solution is pretty simple:

Press Escape. Sometimes you may need to press it twice.

Comment: Confirm, the issue turned out to be simple. Double-escape helped.

Answer (score 3):

"Settings > Editor > Color & Fonts > Java", in the Scheme then find '**Constant (static final field)**' and choose the color you want.

**Upd.:**
Screenshot

[image]

**Upd. 2:**
The answer from MatF is the solution to the actual problem asked about.

Comment: My case is different than what  you have suggested. it affects only local variables, not the imported.

Comment: @VikasPatidar can you then elaborate a little more?

Comment: Does changing the `background` field to white not remove the highlight?

Comment: @Marko no, it doesn't changes anything for imported static constants or members

Comment: I have an imported constant 'android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat#SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM' and changed its color to red.

Comment: @khusrav did you used static import?

Comment: @VikasPatidar yes. Let me try to prepare a screenshot

Comment: @VikasPatidar khusrav's solution works for me (with import static android.opengl.GLES20.*; constants). Maybe you coluld provide list of items in Colors&Fonts->Java that have non-empty background field?

Comment: @khusrav I think you have misunderstood the question, I want to stop highlights for used constants/members which are related to static imports. While your screenshot shows static import with different colors.

Comment: @VikasPatidar it shows it like this across the code. So, if you want it to be no different from other code, check off its foreground color. It will affect all the constants, local and imported. Otherwise, don't understand what do you want.

Comment: @khusrav Thanks for your quick support, though what you suggested in your answer as well as in comments, I already tried before posting the question. Now I have figured out the problem comes when we use `Add static import for constant or method` using `ALT + ENTER` shortcut key and then Android Studio imports all as bunch imports using *, then all the static constants/members related to that imports becomes highlighted and they remains same unless I don't close and reopen the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to use another **Scheme** `(Editor - Colors & Fonts - Java)` instead of your current one.

Look at my following screenshots:

**Default Scheme:**

[image: Default Scheme]

**Obsidian Scheme:**

[image: Obsidian Scheme]

**Customized Scheme:**
At `Constant (static final field)`: uncheck `"Use inherited attributes"`, then set `Background` color

[image: Customized Scheme]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already used what you suggested, including other themes. The problem comes only when we use Add static import for constant or method which was already being used with fully qualified class names using ALT + ENTER shortcut key and then Android Studio imports all as bunch imports using *, then all the static constants/members related to that imports becomes highlighted and they remains same unless I don't close and reopen the file. I will explain all in another post.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate the efforts of @khusrav & @BKN, indeed after reading both of the answers I'm convinced that these are the same tricks I used even before posting the question.

However the issue is quite simple that Android Studio doesn't stop highlights of `static import` related `members` and `constants`.

The problem comes only when I use Add static import for constant or method which was already being used with fully qualified class names using `ALT + ENTER` shortcut key and then Android Studio imports all as bunch imports using * or separate import for every method and constant, then all the static constants/members related to that imports becomes highlighted and they remains same unless I don't close and reopen the file.

Here I am adding 4 screenshots really explains the problem and solution.

> **1) Usual imports with fully qualified names.**

[image]

> **2) Importing on demand static using ALT+ENTER.**

[image]

> **3) Highlighted static members after imports.**

[image]

> **4) Static members after reopening.**

[image]

In short the highlights only goes after you reopen the files.

Comment: You don't have to reopen the file. See my answer for a quicker solution.

Comment: Actualy I really want to highlight this case. Is there any?

Comment: I didn't get what actually you want? Please explain